# Faulty usb device: how to disable to get rid of dmesg errors

Tags: drivers, usb, syslog, dmesg

I bought a second hand computer, which seems to have a faulty USB port (or something - I haven't encountered it). The only real annoyance is that my syslogs are spammed with the same messages:

```
[2864513.931908] usb usb4-port2: cannot disable (err = -32)
[2864518.003911] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[2864518.003925] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
```

That three errors every four to five seconds. Due to these, it's hard to notice all the *actual/important* stuff.

I would like to get rid of these, but I cannot disable USB altogether, as I need it from time to time. Also, it seems the built-in camera is using USB somehow, so the driver seems needed.

Is there some way of disabling usb4-port2 to avoid these errors showing?